# How to handle exception in if condition using watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to check whether `span` with `id` = `"Error_Title"` exists or not. I am getting time out exception due to this condition. I do not know where the exception should be handled in this type of condition.

```
if(ie.span(:id,"Error_Title").exists?)
  puts "yes it is there"
end
```

Comment: if you are using `#exists?` method...there is no chance to get an exception..you will simple get `true` or `false` ...

Comment: @Babai The OP explicitly mentioned he's getting an "time out exception", so apparently it *is* possible :-)

Comment: Could you please paste stack error trace here ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [How can I avoid program termination caused by watir-webdriver timeout error while loading a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043696/how-can-i-avoid-program-termination-caused-by-watir-webdriver-timeout-error-whil) , this should work(untested):

```
begin
  if(ie.span(:id,"Error_Title").exists?)
    puts "yes it is there"
  end 
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Gotcha!"
end
```

Comment: Oh! I missed this line *am getting time out exception due to this condition*.. :)